# Trying to connect my application with SQL Server using sql_server_socket. In SqlConnection.dart the guinness package's version is not specified right

Tags: sql-server, flutter, dart, dependencies, sqlconnection

```js
// Copyright (c) 2015, <your name>. All rights reserved. Use of this source code
// is governed by a BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

library sql_server_socket_test;

import '../lib/sqlconnection.dart';
import '../lib/table.dart';
import '../lib/sqlformats.dart';

import 'dart:async';

//Error occurs here(Couldn't get pub because of wrong version specification)
import "package:guinness/guinness.dart";

void main()
{
   defineSpecs().then((_){});
}   

Future defineSpecs() async
{  
   /// creates a common database where to perform all tests
   
   var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;");
   //var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=DEVIL\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=;");
   
   await conn.open();
   await conn.execute("IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = 'sql_server_socket_test_db') DROP DATABASE sql_server_socket_test_db");
   await conn.execute("CREATE DATABASE sql_server_socket_test_db");
   await conn.execute("USE sql_server_socket_test_db");
   await conn.execute("CREATE TABLE Customers (Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(64), Age INT, Born DATETIME, HasWebSite BIT NOT NULL)");
   await conn.execute("INSERT INTO Customers (Name, Age, HasWebSite) VALUES ('Bob' ,33, 0)");
   await conn.execute("INSERT INTO Customers (Name, Age, HasWebSite, Born) VALUES ('Tom' ,42, 1, ${sqlDate(new DateTime(1972,05,03))})");
   await conn.execute("INSERT INTO Customers (Name, Age, HasWebSite) VALUES ('Mary',18, 1)");
   await conn.close();
      
   conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=sql_server_socket_test_db;Trusted_Connection=yes;");
   //conn = new SqlConnection("Server=DEVIL\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=sql_server_socket_test_db;User Id=sa;Password=;");
  
   describe("SQL formatting functions", ()
   {
       describe("sqlDate()", ()  
       {
          it("returns a SQL formatted date", ()
          {
             var d = sqlDate(new DateTime(1980,5,3));             
             expect(d).toEqual("CONVERT(DATETIME,'1980-05-03 00:00:00.000',102)");             
          });
       });   
    
       describe("sqlBool()", ()  
       {
          it("converts true and false into 1 and 0", ()
          {                 
             expect(sqlBool(false)).toEqual("0");
             expect(sqlBool(true )).toEqual("1");         
          });
       });
    
       describe("sqlString()", ()
       {    
          it("sqlString() formats a string to SQL, keeping care of single quotes", ()
          {                 
             expect(sqlString("ONE'TWO''THREE'''")).toEqual("'ONE''TWO''''THREE'''''''");                  
          });
       });
   });

   // TODO connection tests (ports/service running etc)
   
   describe('SqlConnection methods', ()  
   {   
      beforeEach(() async
      {
         await conn.open();
      });
      
      afterEach(() async
      {
         await conn.close();
      });

      describe("execute()", ()
      {
         it("returns the number of rows effected", () async
         {
            var n = await conn.execute("UPDATE Customers SET HasWebSite=1 WHERE HasWebSite=1");
            expect(n).toEqual(2);
         });
         
         it("does UPDATE commands correctly when not changing anything", () async
         {
            var n = await conn.execute("UPDATE Customers SET HasWebSite=1 WHERE HasWebSite=1");
            expect(n).toEqual(2);
         });
            
         it("returns 0 when nothing done", () async
         {
            var n = await conn.execute("UPDATE Customers SET HasWebSite=1 WHERE 0=1");
            expect(n).toEqual(0);            
         });
            
         it("does UPDATE commands correctly", () async
         {
            var n = await conn.execute("UPDATE Customers SET Name='Bill' WHERE Name='Bob'");
            expect(n).toEqual(1);            
 
            var n1 = await conn.queryValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers WHERE Name='Bob'");
            var n2 = await conn.queryValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers WHERE Name='Bill'");
            expect(n1).toEqual(0);
            expect(n2).toEqual(1);

            n = await conn.execute("UPDATE Customers SET Name='Bob' WHERE Name='Bill'");  // reverts back 
            expect(n).toEqual(1);
         });         
      });
      
      describe("queryValue()", ()
      {
         it("returns null when querying empty rows", () async
         {                  
            // no customers named 'Mark'
            var n = await conn.queryValue("SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Name='Mark'");
            expect(n,null);
         });
         
         it("returns an integer value from query", () async
         {
            // Mary's Age is 18
            var age = await conn.queryValue("SELECT Age FROM Customers WHERE Name='Mary'");
            expect(age,18);
         });
         
         it("returns a boolean from query", () async
         {
            // Mary has a web site
            var bit = await conn.queryValue("SELECT HasWebSite FROM Customers WHERE Name='Mary'");
            expect(bit,true);
         });
         
         it("returns a String from query", () async
         {
            // Bob does not have a website
            var name = await conn.queryValue("SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE HasWebSite=0");
            expect(name,"Bob");
         });

         it("returns null when queried field is null", () async
         {         
            // First customer does not have a date
            var born = await conn.queryValue("SELECT Born FROM Customers");
            expect(born,null);
         });
                  
         it("returns a DateTime from query", () async
         {            
            var tomsborn = await conn.queryValue("SELECT Born FROM Customers WHERE Name = 'Tom'");
            expect(tomsborn is DateTime).toEqual(true);
            expect(tomsborn).toEqual(new DateTime(1972,05,03));
         });               
      });

      describe("querySingle()", ()
      {
         it("returns null when querying empty rows", () async
         {                  
            // no customers named 'Mark'
            var n = await conn.querySingle("SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Name='Mark'");
            expect(n).toEqual(null);
         });      
         
         it("returns a row from query", () async
         {                  
            // tom's row
            var row = await conn.querySingle("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Name='Tom'");
            expect(row is Map).toEqual(true);
            expect(row).toEqual({ "Id": 2, "Name": 'Tom' , "Age": 42, "HasWebSite": true,  "Born": new DateTime(1972,05,03) });
         });      
      });   

      describe("query()", ()
      {
         it("returns an empty List when querying empty rows", () async
         {                  
            // no customers named 'Mark'
            var q = await conn.query("SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Name='Mark'");
            expect(q).toEqual([]);
         });      
         
         it("returns rows from query", () async
         {                  
            var q = await conn.query("SELECT Name, Age, HasWebSite, Born FROM Customers ORDER BY Id");
            
            expect(q is List).toEqual(true);
            expect(q.length).toEqual(3);
            expect(q).toEqual(
            [
               { "Name": 'Bob' , "Age": 33, "HasWebSite": false, "Born": null },
               { "Name": 'Tom' , "Age": 42, "HasWebSite": true,  "Born": new DateTime(1972,05,03) },
               { "Name": 'Mary', "Age": 18, "HasWebSite": true,  "Born": null } 
            ]);

         });      
      });
      
      describe("queryTable()", ()
      {
         it("when result is empty, returns no rows and filled column info", () async
         {                  
            // no customers named 'Mark'
            var table = await conn.queryTable("SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Name='Mark'");
            expect(table.rows.length).toEqual(0);
            expect(table.columns.length).toEqual(2); // Primary key Id is always included
         });      

         it("returns a full datased", () async
         {                  
            // no customers named 'Mark'
            var table = await conn.queryTable("SELECT Id, Name, Age, HasWebSite, Born FROM Customers ORDER BY Id");
            expect(table.tableName).toEqual("Customers");
            expect(table.rows.length).toEqual(3);
            expect(table.columns.length).toEqual(5); 
            expect(table.rows).toEqual(
            [
               { "Id": 1, "Name": 'Bob' , "Age": 33, "HasWebSite": false, "Born": null                     , "_originalIndex": 0 },
               { "Id": 2, "Name": 'Tom' , "Age": 42, "HasWebSite": true,  "Born": new DateTime(1972,05,03) , "_originalIndex": 1 },
               { "Id": 3, "Name": 'Mary', "Age": 18, "HasWebSite": true,  "Born": null                     , "_originalIndex": 2 }
            ]);
         });      
      });
   });        
}
```

```js
library sql_server_socket;

import "dart:io";
import "dart:async";
import "dart:convert";
import 'dart:typed_data';

import "table.dart";

class SqlConnection {
  late Socket _socket;
  late StringBuffer _receiveBuffer;
  late Completer _completer;
  late bool _connected;

  late String _address;
  late int _port;
  late String _connectionString;

  SqlConnection(String connStr,
      {String address: "localhost", int port: 10980}) {
    _address = address;
    _port = port;
    _connected = false;
    _connectionString = connStr;
  }

  /// tells if database is connected
  bool get connected => _connected;

  /// connects to sql server database using the specified connection string
  Future<bool> open() async {
    try {
      this._socket = await Socket.connect(_address, _port);
      //print("Connected to: ${_socket.remoteAddress.address}:${_socket.remotePort}");
    } catch (ex) {
      // throw "can't connect to ${_address}:${_port} -- $ex";
      throw "can't connect to $_address:$_port -- $ex";
    }

    //Establish the onData, and onDone callbacks
    _socket
        .transform(utf8.decoder as StreamTransformer<Uint8List, dynamic>)
        .listen(_receiveData, onError: _onError, onDone: _onDone);

    Completer<bool> connectCompleter = new Completer();

    // String json = JSON.encode({"type": "open", "text": _connectionString});
    String json = jsonEncode({"type": "open", "text": _connectionString});

    _sendCommand(json).then((result) {
      var res = _parseResult(result);
      if (res is _OkResult) {
        _connected = true;
        connectCompleter.complete(true);
      } else if (res is _ErrorResult) {
        _connected = false;
        connectCompleter.completeError(res.error);
      } else
        throw "unknown response";
    }).catchError((err) {
      _connected = false;
      connectCompleter.completeError(err);
    });

    return connectCompleter.future;
  }

  /// disconnects from sql server
  Future<bool> close() {
    if (!connected) throw "not connected";

    Completer<bool> disconnectCompleter = new Completer();

    String json = jsonEncode({"type": "close", "text": ""});

    _sendCommand(json).then((risp) {
      var res = _parseResult(risp);

      if (res is _OkResult) {
        _connected = false;
        disconnectCompleter.complete(true);
      } else if (res is _ErrorResult) {
        disconnectCompleter.completeError(res.error);
      } else
        throw "unknown response";
    }).catchError((err) {
      disconnectCompleter.completeError(err);
    });

    return Future.value(disconnectCompleter.future);
  }

  /// launch a query on the database, returning a table
  Future<Table> queryTable(String sql) {
    if (!connected) throw "not connected";

    String json = jsonEncode({"type": "table", "text": sql});

    Completer<Table> compl = new Completer();
    _sendCommand(json).then((result) {
      var res = _parseResult(result);

      if (res is _ErrorResult)
        compl.completeError(res.error);
      else if (res is _TableResult) {
        var tres = res;
        Table tab = new Table(this, tres.tableName, tres.rows, tres.columns);
        compl.complete(tab);
      } else
        throw "unknown response";
    }).catchError((err) {
      compl.completeError(err);
    });
    return compl.future;
  }

  Future<PostBackResponse> postBack(ChangeSet chg) {
    if (!connected) throw "not connected";

    String params = jsonEncode(chg.toEncodable());

    String json = jsonEncode({"type": "postback", "text": params});

    Completer<PostBackResponse> compl = new Completer();
    _sendCommand(json).then((result) {
      var res = _parseResult(result);

      if (res is _ErrorResult)
        compl.completeError(res.error);
      else if (res is _PostBackResult) {
        var tres = res;
        PostBackResponse resp = new PostBackResponse();
        resp.idcolumn = tres.idcolumn;
        resp.identities = tres.identities;
        compl.complete(resp);
      } else
        throw "invalid postback response";
    }).catchError((err) {
      compl.completeError(err);
    });
    return compl.future;
  }

  /// launch a query on the database, returning all rows
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> query(String sql) {
    if (!connected) throw "not connected";

    String json = jsonEncode({"type": "query", "text": sql});

    Completer<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> compl = new Completer();
    _sendCommand(json).then((result) {
      var res = _parseResult(result);
      if (res is _ErrorResult)
        compl.completeError(res.error);
      else if (res is _QueryResult)
        compl.complete(res.rows);
      else
        throw "unknown response";
    }).catchError((err) {
      compl.completeError(err);
    });
    return compl.future;
  }

  /// launch a query on the database, returning the first rows only
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> querySingle(String sql) {
    if (!connected) throw "not connected";

    String json = jsonEncode({"type": "querysingle", "text": sql});

    Completer<Map<String, dynamic>> compl = new Completer();
    _sendCommand(json).then((result) {
      var res = _parseResult(result);

      if (res is _ErrorResult)
        compl.completeError(res.error);
      else if (res is _QueryResult) {
        if (res.rows.length == 0)
          compl.complete(null);
        else
          compl.complete(res.rows[0]);
      } else
        throw "unknown response";
    }).catchError((err) {
      compl.completeError(err);
    });
    return compl.future;
  }

  /// launch a query on the database, returning the value from the first column of the first row
  Future<dynamic> queryValue(String sql) {
    if (!connected) throw "not connected";

    String json = jsonEncode({"type": "queryvalue", "text": sql});

    Completer compl = new Completer();
    _sendCommand(json).then((result) {
      var res = _parseResult(result);

      if (res is _ErrorResult)
        compl.completeError(res.error);
      else if (res is _QueryResult) {
        if (res.rows.length == 0)
          compl.complete(null);
        else
          compl.complete(res.rows[0]["value"]);
      } else
        throw "unknown response";
    }).catchError((err) {
      compl.completeError(err);
    });
    return compl.future;
  }

  /// executes a sql command, returning the number of rows affected
  Future<int> execute(String sql) {
    if (!connected) throw "not connected";

    String json = jsonEncode({"type": "execute", "text": sql});

    Completer<int> compl = new Completer();
    _sendCommand(json).then((result) {
      var res = _parseResult(result);

      if (res is _ErrorResult)
        compl.completeError(res.error);
      else if (res is _QueryResult) {
        if (res.rows.length == 0)
          compl.complete(-1);
        else
          compl.complete(res.rows[0]["rowsAffected"]);
      } else
        throw "unknown response";
    }).catchError((err) {
      compl.completeError(err);
    });
    return compl.future;
  }

  /// formats and write a command to the socket
  Future<String> _sendCommand(String command) {
    // prepare buffer for response
    _receiveBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    Completer<String> _completer = new Completer();
    String cmd = command.length.toString() + "\r\n" + command;
    _socket.write(cmd);

    return _completer.future;
  }

  void _onDone() {
    //print("onDone()");
    //socket.destroy();
  }

  void _onError(error) {
    print("error occurred: $error");
  }

  /// receive data from socket and build a command string
  ///
  /// client sends text-based commands with the format:
  /// size_of_command_string + "\r\n" + command_string
  void _receiveData(data) {
    _receiveBuffer.write(data);

    String content = _receiveBuffer.toString();

    if (content.indexOf("\r\n") > 0) {
      int x = content.indexOf("\r\n");
      int len = int.parse(content.substring(0, x)); // size of command string

      String cmd = content.substring(x + 2);
      if (cmd.length == len) {
        _completer.complete(cmd);
      }
    }
  }

  /// translates generic json result into a Result type
  dynamic _parseResult(String json) {
    Map result = jsonDecode(json);

    if (result["type"] == "ok")
      return new _OkResult("ok");
    else if (result["type"] == "error")
      return new _ErrorResult(result["error"]);
    else if (result["type"] == "query")
      return new _QueryResult(result["rows"], result["columns"]);
    else if (result["type"] == "table")
      return new _TableResult(
          result["tablename"], result["rows"], result["columns"]);
    else if (result["type"] == "postback")
      return new _PostBackResult(result["idcolumn"], result["identities"]);
    else
      throw "unknown response";
  }
}

class _ErrorResult {
  late String error;

  _ErrorResult(String error) {
    this.error = error;
  }
}

class _OkResult {
  late String ok;

  _OkResult(String ok) {
    this.ok = ok;
  }
}

class _QueryResult {
  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> rows;
  late Map<String, dynamic> columns;

  _QueryResult(List<Map<String, dynamic>> rows, Map<String, dynamic> columns) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;

    // fix types
    for (var fieldName in columns.keys) {
      TypeFixer.fixColumn(rows, fieldName, columns[fieldName]);
    }
  }
}

class _TableResult {
  late String tableName;
  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> rows;
  late List<Map<String, String>> columns;

  _TableResult(String tableName, List<Map<String, dynamic>> rows,
      List<Map<String, String>> columns) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;
  }
}

class _PostBackResult {
  late String idcolumn;
  late List<int> identities;

  _PostBackResult(String idcolumn, List<int> identities) {
    this.idcolumn = idcolumn;
    this.identities = identities;
  }
}

/// translates a JSON encoded SQL type into a Dart type
class TypeFixer {
  /// fix string data type coming from JSON into proper Dart data type
  static void fixColumn(
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> rows, String columnName, String columnType) {
    if (columnType == "datetime") {
      for (int t = 0; t < rows.length; t++) {
        if (rows[t][columnName] != null)
          rows[t][columnName] = DateTime.parse(rows[t][columnName]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
pubspec.yaml

name: sql_server_socket
version: 0.0.1
description: A minimal command-line application.
#author: <Antonino Porcino> <nino.porcino@gmail.com>
#homepage: https://github.com/nippur72/SqlServerSocket
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
#dependencies:
#  foo_bar: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
dev_dependencies:
  unittest: any
  guinness: ">=1.3.0 <2.0.0"
```

I'm using Flutter Dart to develop an application, in that I'm trying to establish Sql connection with Sql server and application.
This is the link I referred for connection https://github.com/nippur72/SqlServerSocket .
While trying to add dependencies in pubspec.yaml, under dev_dependencies the version of guinness is not updating to the newer version(pub update). While clicking pub get i'm receiving this error,

Resolving dependencies...
Because sql_server_socket depends on guinness ^1.3.0 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
Process finished with exit code 1
[image]

I have tried specifying the version manually and i know it doesn't work that way. So I used pub update, tried updating the whole flutter and dart version, yet receiving the same error.
Is there any other solution other than guinness? Or how can I get the actual guinness version. I have tried surfing thru internet for guinness versions but had no relevant result.
Please help me with this issue. I've been stuck with sql connection for past few days.

[image]
Thanks in advance!

[image]
Error message

Comment: Are you sure your application should *directly* connect to your database server? That seems super insecure for most cases.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm developing this application for Offline use and it needs to be stored locally. In this case instead of using API integration I have chose this method. Is there any solution rather than connecting directly to the database server? If so can you help me with that please

Comment: If it needs to be stored locally, SQL Server is a very weird choice for a Flutter app. Are you programming a Windows only Flutter app, or did I miss something about SQL Server?

Comment: As you said "offline" and "locally", I'm assuming you are not programming a web application, but indeed an app on devices. Have you looked into https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite ?

Comment: I'm developing a Mobile application and I'm trying to use an existing MSSQL database in Flutter. So the problem is I couldn't load external database into this project. Sqflite package does not support this particular thing. I tired SQLite studio, Microsoft SQL server management studio etc and finally decided to end up with MSSQL coz the previously  used database does not use SQLite. Also the first reference i looked into was https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite .In this app the version doesn't update even though we force it to. What can I do to fix this issue? Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: How do you supposed to open a MSSQL database on your device? Does it run SQL Server? The package you have and you are having trouble with connects to a remote machine. A remote windows machine running SQL Server and it does so by starting a windows executable on that machine. so before you spent a lot of time trying to fix this package, do you really think what I described is what you need? A connection to a remote windows machine running SQL Server?

Comment: @nvoigt I had ideas to fetch data locally from application using SQL server in my Flutter Dart application. Since I got stuck in-between this problem I have no clue what to do next. Actually I don't necessarily want connection to a remote windows machine that runs SQL server. Please help me with connecting SQL server with my application(Not Directly since its not advisable). I just need an external database to connect with my application. I am ready to follow a new approach that results with SQL connection.

Comment: Can you explain what your *requirement* is? In plain English? Forget about Flutter forget about what you already have. What is this app supposed to do? You said something about "offline". Is it supposed to work without being connected to the internet at times?

Comment: @nvoigt I need to create a Quiz application that runs offline in places that have no network or poor connection. The responses are stored locally in phone's storage when offline and when online the stored data can be flushed and synced to server database or cloud. So the app requirement is to have an amazing UI design and the branching logic is used to map questions according to the answer previously clicked. Kindly guide me to create an application that fulfils these requirements.

Comment: For local storage, you cannot use SQL Server. Because it does not run on devices. You can use SQL server for your backend database when connectivity is on. However, even then you would connect to a backend software, which in turn connects to the database. That backend software handles things like authentication/authorization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237476/discussion-between-terin-tittu-and-nvoigt).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *SQLite* to store data locally and then use the package *sql_conn 0.0.3* to do the insert/update operations on SQL Server.

I am going to try this suggestion myself this month, and will comment on my results.

Comment: I am going to build an app which involves similar task, so can I know the result?

Comment: I finally migrated the data to Firebase FireStore Database. It works on Android and Web. The previous version (with mySQL), I left running on Windows.